# How to use functions to generate an automated table of risk ratios and attack rates for a set of variables

Tags: r, function, frequency-table

I have a foodborne outbreak dataset (I made up the data in this example for privacy reasons) of foods at a picnic that tells which people ate the food and which people got sick. I would like to create functions and code to generate a table with automated calculations of attack rate and risk ratio.

First, this is the dataset I have:

```
patient sick apple banana strawberry yogurt sandwich
1: patient1  yes    no     no        yes     no       no
2: patient2  yes   yes     no         no    yes       no
3: patient3   no   yes    yes        yes    yes      yes
4: patient4  yes    no     no        yes    yes       no
5: patient5   no    no     no         no    yes       no
6: patient6   no    no     no         no     no       no
7: patient7  yes    no     no         no    yes      yes
```

To calculate the attack rate (in this case for an apple), I use this code:

```
sick_apple <- picnic %>% 
  group_by(sick, apple) %>% 
  summarise(total=n())
sick_apple
```

This gives an output like this (sick=="yes" means they got sick, and apple=="yes" means they ate an apple):

```
# A tidytable: 4 × 3
# Groups:      sick
  sick  apple total
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 no    no        2
2 no    yes       1
3 yes   no        3
4 yes   yes       1
```

In this example, the attack rate for people who ate an apple is the number of people who ate an apple and got sick, divided by the total number of people who ate an apple, in this case 1/(1+1)=0.5. The attack rate for people who did not eat an apple would therefore be 3/(3+2)=0.6.

Okay, so now for the risk ratio. This one is a little more complex to calculate and I use a function from the epitools package to do this one. To calculate the risk ratio for an apple I use this code:

```
apple_table <- matrix(c(2,1,3,1), nrow=2, ncol=2)
apple_table
riskratio.wald(apple_table)
```

This gives an output that looks like this:

```
> apple_table <- matrix(c(2,1,3,1), nrow=2, ncol=2)
> apple_table
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    3
[2,]    1    1
> riskratio.wald(apple_table)
$data
          Outcome
Predictor  Disease1 Disease2 Total
  Exposed1        2        3     5
  Exposed2        1        1     2
  Total           3        4     7

$measure
          risk ratio with 95% C.I.
Predictor   estimate     lower    upper
  Exposed1 1.0000000        NA       NA
  Exposed2 0.8333333 0.1751513 3.964825

$p.value
          two-sided
Predictor  midp.exact fisher.exact chi.square
  Exposed1         NA           NA         NA
  Exposed2  0.8571429            1  0.8091498

$correction
[1] FALSE

attr(,"method")
[1] "Unconditional MLE & normal approximation (Wald) CI"
```

In the section of output under $measure, the risk ratio is 0.83333.

So those are the calculations that I am concerned with. What I want to do next (but have no idea how to do) is use this to generate an automated table for a list of foods that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 8
  food_item  ate_got_sick total.1 ate_attack_rate didnt_eat_got_sick total.2 didnt_eat_attack_rate risk_ratio
  <chr>             <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>              <dbl>   <dbl>                 <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Apple                 1       2           0.5                    3       5                 0.6        0.833
2 Banana                0       1           0                      4       6                 0.667      0    
3 Strawberry            2       3           0.667                  2       4                 0.5        1.33 
4 Yogurt                3       5           0.6                    1       2                 0.5        1.33 
5 Sandwich              1       2           0.5                    3       5                 0.6        1.11
```

Or, if this is easier to visualize, this table:
[image]